# JavaFX Adding a MouseEvent to a bar inside of a BarChart

Tags: events, javafx-2, mouseevent, bar-chart, javafx-8

So i am trying to create an application that has values on a chart, which shows normally. However i am also trying to add a mouse event that is called when i click on a particular bar of the bar graph. More specifically it updates a status bar with some more detail pulled from the database.

```
Group root = new Group();
String[] years = {"Opened", "Closed", "Still Opened"};
CategoryAxis xAxis = new CategoryAxis();
xAxis.setCategories(FXCollections.observableArrayList(years));
NumberAxis yAxis = new NumberAxis("Jobs", 0.0d, 1, .2);
BarChart.Series<String, ObservableList> s1 = new BarChart.Series("51 ",                                        FXCollections.observableArrayList(
                new BarChart.Data(years[0], Math.random()),
                new BarChart.Data(years[1], Math.random()),
                new BarChart.Data(years[2], Math.random())));;

        BarChart.Series<String, ObservableList> s2 = new BarChart.Series("52 ", FXCollections.observableArrayList(
                new BarChart.Data(years[0], Math.random()),
                new BarChart.Data(years[1], Math.random()),
                new BarChart.Data(years[2], Math.random())));

        BarChart.Series<String, ObservableList> s3 = new BarChart.Series("53 ", FXCollections.observableArrayList(
                new BarChart.Data(years[0], Math.random()),
                new BarChart.Data(years[1], Math.random()),
                new BarChart.Data(years[2], Math.random())));

        BarChart.Series<String, ObservableList> s4 = new BarChart.Series("54 ", FXCollections.observableArrayList(
                new BarChart.Data(years[0], Math.random()),
                new BarChart.Data(years[1], Math.random()),
                new BarChart.Data(years[2], Math.random())));

        ObservableList barChartData = FXCollections.observableArrayList(s1,s2,s3,s4);

        this.statusMessage.setText("Setting listener");
        for (XYChart.Data<String, ObservableList> dt : s1.getData()) 
        { 
            statusMessage.setText("Acting on: " + dt.getXValue());
            dt.getNode().setOnMouseClicked((MouseEvent event) -> {
                statusMessage.setText("Clicked");
            }); 
        }

        BarChart chart = new BarChart(xAxis, yAxis, barChartData, 25.0d);
```

this application will compile with and without the event, but with the event when i create the chart it fails and is unable to show it. I assume its because the event is not being loaded to the bar

The errors i get:

```
Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$MethodHandler.invoke(FXMLLoader.java:1768)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ControllerMethodEventHandler.handle(FXMLLoader.java:1651)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:86)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:238)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:191)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventDispatcher.java:59)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:58)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(EventUtil.java:74)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(EventUtil.java:49)
    at javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Event.java:204)
    at javafx.scene.Node.fireEvent(Node.java:8175)
    at javafx.scene.control.Button.fire(Button.java:185)
    at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.behavior.ButtonBehavior.mouseReleased(ButtonBehavior.java:182)
    at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.BehaviorSkinBase$1.handle(BehaviorSkinBase.java:96)
    at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.BehaviorSkinBase$1.handle(BehaviorSkinBase.java:89)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler$NormalEventHandlerRecord.handleBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:218)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:80)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:238)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:191)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventDispatcher.java:59)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:58)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(EventUtil.java:74)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(EventUtil.java:54)
    at javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Event.java:204)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.process(Scene.java:3746)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.access$1800(Scene.java:3471)
    at javafx.scene.Scene.impl_processMouseEvent(Scene.java:1695)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$ScenePeerListener.mouseEvent(Scene.java:2486)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:314)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:243)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.handleMouseEvent(GlassViewEventHandler.java:345)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.View.handleMouseEvent(View.java:526)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.View.notifyMouse(View.java:898)
```

Comment: Just a guess I haven't tried but the docs say use a [node](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/chart/XYChart.Data.html#nodeProperty) for mouse listeners.

Comment: JavaFx utilizes nodes as the components inside of an application.

Comment: I think you just have to add your getNode() after the `BarChart chart = new BarChart...`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the [Oracle sample](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/charts/bar-chart.htm) with some stuff cut out.  Look down where I added the loop to get the nodes of the bars and added listeners.

```
package barchartsample;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.chart.BarChart;
import javafx.scene.chart.CategoryAxis;
import javafx.scene.chart.NumberAxis;
import javafx.scene.chart.XYChart;
import javafx.scene.input.MouseEvent;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class BarChartSample extends Application {
    final static String austria = "Austria";
    final static String brazil = "Brazil";

    @Override public void start(Stage stage) {
        stage.setTitle("Bar Chart Sample");
        final CategoryAxis xAxis = new CategoryAxis();
        final NumberAxis yAxis = new NumberAxis();
        final BarChart<String,Number> bc = new BarChart(xAxis,yAxis);
        bc.setTitle("Country Summary");
        xAxis.setLabel("Country");       
        yAxis.setLabel("Value");

        XYChart.Series series1 = new XYChart.Series();
        series1.setName("2003");       
        series1.getData().add(new XYChart.Data(austria, 25601.34));
        series1.getData().add(new XYChart.Data(brazil, 20148.82));

        Scene scene  = new Scene(bc,800,600);
        bc.getData().addAll(series1);
        //now you can get the nodes.
        for (Series<String,Number> serie: bc.getData()){
            for (XYChart.Data<String, Number> item: serie.getData()){
                item.getNode().setOnMousePressed((MouseEvent event) -> {
                    System.out.println("you clicked "+item.toString()+serie.toString());
                });
            }
        }
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```