# Adding Tooltip or Label to xAxis CategoryData Chart on JAVAFX

Tags: java, javafx, charts, tooltip

I get example from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23186914/javafx-adding-a-mouseevent-to-a-bar-inside-of-a-barchart) and I expect to Tooltip for each xAxis Data Category of BarChart (Country name) So that I can see Tooltip while Cursor at each Country name like[image]
Here is the code

```
public class BarChartSample extends Application {
final static String austria = "Austria";
final static String brazil = "Brazil";

@Override public void start(Stage stage) {
    stage.setTitle("Bar Chart Sample");
    final CategoryAxis xAxis = new CategoryAxis();
    final NumberAxis yAxis = new NumberAxis();
    final BarChart<String,Number> bc = new BarChart(xAxis,yAxis);
    bc.setTitle("Country Summary");
    xAxis.setLabel("Country");       
    yAxis.setLabel("Value");

    XYChart.Series series1 = new XYChart.Series();
    series1.setName("2003");       
    series1.getData().add(new XYChart.Data(austria, 25601.34));
    series1.getData().add(new XYChart.Data(brazil, 20148.82));


    Scene scene  = new Scene(bc,800,600);
    bc.getData().addAll(series1);

    //now you can get the nodes.
    for (Series<String,Number> serie: bc.getData()){
        for (XYChart.Data<String, Number> item: serie.getData()){
            item.getNode().setOnMousePressed((MouseEvent event) -> {
                System.out.println("you clicked "+item.toString()+serie.toString());
            });
        }
    }
    stage.setScene(scene);
    stage.show();
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    launch(args);
}

}
```

I'm looking hearing from you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the code.. as you can set event handlers to the node, you can also set the tooltip to the node.

```
for (XYChart.Series<String, Number> series : bc.getData()) {
    for (XYChart.Data<String, Number> item : series.getData()) {
        item.getNode().setOnMousePressed((MouseEvent event) -> {
            System.out.println("you clicked " + item.toString() + series.toString());
        });
        Tooltip.install(item.getNode(), new Tooltip(item.getXValue() + ":\n" + item.getYValue()));
    }
}
```

**Update::**

As per your requirement, if you want the tooltip on the axis label, you can try the below approach. I believe this is not the right approach but it can give you some results. Also I am not sure what you want to show in tooltips if you have multiple series.

```
xAxis.getChildrenUnmodifiable().addListener((ListChangeListener<Node>) p -> {
    if (p.next()) {
        p.getAddedSubList().forEach(node -> {
            if (node != null && node instanceof Text) {
                final Text textNode = (Text) node;
                final Optional<XYChart.Data<String, Number>> data = bc.getData().get(0).getData().stream().filter(item -> item.getXValue().equalsIgnoreCase(textNode.getText())).findFirst();
                data.ifPresent(d -> {
                    Tooltip.install(textNode, new Tooltip(d.getXValue() + ":\n" + d.getYValue()));
                });
            }
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: please see my image I posted when move cursor to "Austria"  Then Tooltip is displayed . Your Code run to show tooltip while cursor at Column bar

Comment: Great! Thank you so much , It worked for me. Thanks for ur gift :)

Comment: If your question in OP is addressed.. mark it as answered. It may help others :)